# Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) : variable lengths differ (found for 'k')

Tags: r

Don't know what should I put inside model.matrix. I want to put the name inside the name list a to model.matrix

```
a <- row.names(bbb)
a <- noquote(a)
a

for(k in a){ 
  y <- election_data_train$Obama_margin_percent
  x <- model.matrix( Obama_margin_percent ~ .-k-Obama_wins-Obama_margin-FIPS-ElectionDate-TotalVote-Clinton-Obama, data = election_data_train )
  d <- election_data_train[["k"]]

  gg_k <- glm(y~d+x)
  print(summary(gg_k)$coef['d',])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Just add [-1] at the end of the second line of code below:
model.matrix( Obama_margin_percent ~ .-k-Obama_wins-Obama_margin-FIPS-ElectionDate-TotalVote-Clinton-Obama, data = election_data_train )